# Ubuntu server live: "Cannot delete a single partition from a device that already has partitions"

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, 20.04, usb-installation

I downloaded the latest `ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso` and started the installation.
When I reached the storage configuration section, I chose "Custom layout".
The disk already has partitions, so I tried to delete the unnecessary partitions. When selected `Delete` this message popped up: `Cannot delete a single partition from a device that already has partitions`.

The question is how do I delete them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [subiquity bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1868249) about this, and it looks like the installer doesn't support deleting partitions.

Your options are to erase entire disk and create partitions from scratch, or switch to a different console (Alt+F2) and use a different partitioning tool (`parted`, `cfdisk`).